# Working on a Python IRC bot - how can I query the website for title?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

here's my current code:

```
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
title = soup.find('title')[7:(title.len()-7)]
return title
```

Thing is, if I query websites like Wikipedia with this, it crashes with a 403. What can I do about this? (Using python3)

Comment: In the HTTP used on the World Wide Web, 403 Forbidden is an HTTP status code

Comment: Are you doing this recursively/iteratively, or are you sending a single request? What does your 403 message look like?

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia doesn't want you to scrape their site.  They are refusing to serve you because they believe you are scraping, and they are right.

Comment: Nothing I can do about that? Like, is there a way to change my User Agent?

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has a API that you can use to crawl their content ([Wikipedia API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aMain_page)) or you can download their [data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDatabase_download) depending on what you actually want to extract.